# 2 Coldfusion Dates to a list of formated list of dates

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

I have 2 coldfusion dates like

```
from: 2013-03-29 00:00:00.0 
to: 2013-04-05 00:00:00.0
```

I would like to create a list of all dates between these 2 date like

```
29.03.2013,30.03.2013,31.03.2013,......,05.04.2013
```

Is there a function available for that or I have to loop from `date_from` to `date_to` and create a list?

Comment: There is no built in function. You must loop.

Comment: [listFromDateRange()](http://www.cflib.org/udf/listFromDateRange) is a UDF which will give you a list of dates and works in CF versions all the way back to 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, you can loop over dates using cfloop, and the 'index' is the number of days since the Epoch, which you can also treat as a date.  By doing a date function on it, e.g. using dateAdd, it converts it to a date object.

```
<cfset date_From = createDate(2013, 3, 29)>
<cfset date_To = createDate(2013, 4, 5)>

<cfset allDates = []>

<cfloop from="#date_from#" to="#date_to#" index="i">
    <cfoutput>
    #i#<br>
    </cfoutput>

    <!--- adding zero will do nothing to the date other than turn it into a date object --->
    <cfset newDate = dateadd("d", 0, i)>

    <cfset arrayAppend(allDates, newDate)>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#allDates#">
```